# Why are my object-variables null in console log?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am seriously having a mental breakdown over this right now...

I am working on a small vue based website.
In this particular Section I want to add an Item to a List.

Here is my Code:

```
addItem() {
  this.items.push(this.itemToBeProcessed);
  this.itemToBeProcessed.id = null;
  this.itemToBeProcessed.name = "";
  this.itemToBeProcessed.price = null;
  this.itemToBeProcessed.buyers = [];
  this.itemToBeProcessed.amountPurchased = null;
},
async checkInput() {
  let item = this.itemToBeProcessed;
  if (item.name != "" &&
      item.id != null &&
      item.price != null &&
      item.amountPurchased != null &&
      item.buyers != []) {
    console.log(this.itemToBeProcessed.id)
    console.log(this.itemToBeProcessed)
    console.log(this.itemToBeProcessed.id)
    this.addItem();
  } else {
    alert("Not all Fields are set correctly!")
  }
}
```

My Data Structure:

```
data() {
return {
  itemToBeProcessed: {
    id: null,
    name: "",
    price: null,
    amountPurchased: null,
    buyers: [],
  },
  items: [],
}
```

}

As you can see, I tried console logging my itemToBeProcessed.
In the checkInput method I have three console logs. My problem is now that the console writes the correct id every time.
The Item I want to log on the other hand is only correctly logged if I either comment out the resets in addItem() or if I completly comment out the method call. Otherwise all attributes are null, or [].

I have literally no idea how this would be my mistake at all.

Thank you for a response!

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] (use the stack snippet feature of the question editor to provide a live demo). The code you've provided seems to be missing parts essential to understanding how it fits together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add your item with `items.push`, you don't push a *copy* in your list, you push a reference to the same object as `this.itemToBeProcessed`.

So, when you reset all fields on `this.itemToBeProcessed` right after the push, then you're *also* resetting the fields of the element in the list, since it refers to the same object!

A possible solution could be to use a shallow copy:

```
this.items.push(Object.assign({}, this.itemToBeProcessed));
```

Here you push a new object that has all the fields copied from `this.itemToBeProcessed`, this should solve your issue

Below find an example to put into light the underlying issue:

```js
// With an element as a simple type like string, no issue here.
// I'll change element after being pushed, the list stays "the same".

let list = [];
let element = "aaa";

list.push(element);
console.log(list);

element = "bbb";
console.log(list);

element = null;
console.log(list);



// But if we're dealing with objects, changing element would "change the content" of the list as well.
// Objects variables hold _references_ to an object, they internally refer to the same one!
list = [];
element = { name: "aaa" };

list.push(element);
console.log(list);

element.name = "bbb";
console.log(list);

element.name = null;
console.log(list);
```

In your code:

```js
function addItem() {
  console.log("(addItem) Items before push:");
  console.log(this.items);
  console.log("(addItem) Items after push:");
  this.items.push(this.itemToBeProcessed);
  console.log(this.items);
  this.itemToBeProcessed.id = null;
  this.itemToBeProcessed.name = "";
  this.itemToBeProcessed.price = null;
  this.itemToBeProcessed.buyers = [];
  this.itemToBeProcessed.amountPurchased = null;
  console.log("(addItem) Items after having mutated itemToBeProcessed:");
  console.log(this.items);
}

this.items = [];
this.itemToBeProcessed = { id: 123, name: "hello", price: 2.1, buyers: [3, 4, 5]};

console.log("Initial:")
console.log(this.items);
console.log(this.itemToBeProcessed);

console.log("calling addItems...");
addItem(this.itemToBeProcessed);

console.log("after addItems:");
console.log(this.items);
console.log(this.itemToBeProcessed);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It actually fixed my problem to the extend that it works, but I am still extremly confused on why the console log writes the wrong attributes, rather the wrong attributes for the wrong time.

Comment: Yes, I can understand it might be confusing when first dealing with these issues! I was writing a small exemple to show the behavior. Look at my execuatable snippet, feel free to ask more questions here if you need.

Comment: The problem was that, right after you added the element in the list, you are changing (= _mutating_) the same object, through the original variable. I.e. by resetting all fields of this.itemToBeProcessed right after being added, you were _also_ resetting all the fields of the last object in the list. Inserting a new object in the list fixed this "bonding" problem.

Comment: I am very grateful for your solution. My code works now. I am still confused though on why my console log at the end of checkInput() returns:
Correct id
reset Object with all attributes set to null
Correct id

I see my problem in addItem() but still cant understand this inconsistency in the log.

Comment: If you're talking about the consol.log in checkInput, then you can't see the problem there, because that's before you add in the list and reset all the values. 
In `addItems`, try to log the list just after `items.push`, and again at the end of the method.